# How to copy a Cargo target directory between machines of the same architecture

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My Aarch64 machines are a little slow.

When I copy a project, including a `target` directory between machines, the recipient machine's Cargo insists on building everything again from scratch, as if it ignores all the build artefacts from the source machine.

Both Aarch64 machines have identical hardware.  It even happens if I copy a project between harddisks/Linux-OSs on the same Aarch64 machines.

How can I tell Cargo that the target directory is still valid and not to rebuild everything?

Comment: Do you use `rsync`? More than a simple copy, it preserves the metadata (times...). Typical flags are `-avh`

Comment: Yes, I use `rsync -av` or `cp -a`.

Comment: @prog-fh So it should be working?  There isn't any form of system id used, just architecture checking?

Comment: Yes, just checked if I copy with `rsync -av …` between two different systems (both intel CPUs but apart from that very different) it does not recompile. Have you checked that you're running the same Rust version on both systems, the build artifacts are not interchangable between versions.

Comment: @cafce25 They may have been different versions of Rust, as I installed rustup a few months apart.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Update Rust on both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying with something like `rsync -av …` which preserves the metadata between two different systems should work, (it does for me) though since there is no stable ABI build artifacts are not useable across compiler versions so you have to make sure that you're running the exact same Rust version on both systems.